# KS goodness of fit test result for geometric distribution low p-value

Tags: goodness-of-fit, geometric-distribution

I am trying to test if the sampled interval between random events fits a particular geometric distribution, and am pretty lost as to what I'm doing wrong.

Assuming there's nothing wrong with the library,

```
# Take n samples from the geometric distribution
data = scipy.stats.geom.rvs(.2, size=n, random_state=None)

# Perform ks test against the cdf of distribution
print(scipy.stats.kstest(data, lambda x: scipy.stats.geom.cdf(  x, .2)))
```

results in p-values near 0 (1e-5) with sample size of 100. Increasing the sample size causes the p-values to decrease further (eg 1000 samples results in 1e-35), which is the opposite of what I expect.

Am I making some incorrect statistical assumptions? Is something wrong with my methodology? Is goodness of fit testing not what I'm looking for? Are there other statistical tests that I can do instead?

Comment: @Dave Do you have any suggestions on useful methods to tell if something is generated from a certain distribution? Your link suggests that using a test against a specific distribution results in the power being too high to be useful.

Comment: The geometric distribution may be especially problematic for such a test. I don't know how the K-S test is implemented in Scripy, but in R, a `ks.test` to match the ECDF of a sample from a discrete distribution against the CDF of from that distribution often yields warning msg that the test does not give an accurate P-value in the presence of ties. A sample from a geom dist'n with small $p$ will typically have _massive amounts_ of ties: my geom sample of size 1000 with $p=0.1$ had only about 80 uniquely different values. Gave P-val v. near 0. (Visually the ECDF plot matched the CDF just fine.)

Comment: Unless the chance of tied values in your sample is tiny, the KS test is not applicable.  The software should have warned you.  If it did not, find better software.

Comment: In R: `length(unique(rgeom(1000, .1)))` returned $51.$ And `ks.test(rgeom(1000, .1), pgeom, .1)` returns P-val $4.122e-09$ along with `Warning message: ...
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test`